# Add a new image to a view

Tags: android

I am trying to add the same image to a view. I have a timer that will go off every 20 minutes and I want to add an image to show that the user has completed one timer.

After some [research](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) I have found that I need to use an ArrayAdapter. The problem is I don't understand what any of that code is doing. Can someone explain it to me?

What I have found so far is:

```
protected void onCreate(){

//I need to create a gridview (it could be any type of view)
gridLayout = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);//created in Studio GUI

//Create an image
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
myImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

//Create an image list
private List<ImageView> imgs = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

//add images to list (this will need to be added to the timer later)
for (i = 0; i < numberOfTimersHit; i++){
    imgs.add(myImage);
    }

//add the list to an ArrayAdapter
//This is where I need help

//add the ArrayAdapter to the grid
gridLayout.setAdapter(imageViewArrayAdapter);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to correct anything I have missed.

Comment: Probably, I should not answer your question if you don't have a clue about your own code, but send you to Android 101 (or Java?). However, to give you a sense of direction anyway:

Comment: The code is incomplete (most importantly: what is `imageViewArrayAdapter` and how did you create it?) and takes a wrong approach. You should not make a list of the same item and set it to the adapter every time the number of items has changed. In order to repeat the same image n times in a `GridLayout`, increase a variable inside your adapter (a `RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder>`). In `getItemCount()` you return that variable and in `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)` you just return the same `ViewHolder` with an `ImageView` without making use of `position`.

Comment: After some more research it looks like I no nothing about `ArrayAdapters`. I'm starting a new project just so I can work with them and understand them before I continue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need help on implementing the ImageViewArrayAdapter, so here's how:

```
public class ImageViewArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<ImageView> images;

    public ImageViewArrayAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images != null ? images.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return images.get(position);
    }
}
```

then in your code use:

```
//add the list to an ArrayAdapter
//This is where I need help
ImageViewArrayAdapter imageViewArrayAdapter = new ImageViewArrayAdapter(imgs);
```

This may work.